# Can't register component globally VUE 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a reusable button and I want to render it as a separate component @/components/UI/MyButton'. This element i register in 'UI/index.js'

```
import MyButton from "@/components/UI/MyButton";

export default {
  MyButton,
};
```

and then I globally register through the method аorEach in 'main.js'.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import componentsUI from "./components/UI";

const app = createApp(App);

componentsUI.forEach((component) => {
  app.component(component.name, component);
});

app.mount("#app");
```

but method forEach causes an error *"*components_UI__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.default.forEach is not a function"*, and the project is not rendered.
If I do not use this method, then the button is rendered but without styles.

How can I globally register a reusable component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UI/index.js` try to export an array `[]` not an object `{}`:

```js
import MyButton from "@/components/UI/MyButton";

export default [
  MyButton,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In the components directory create the base folder then create _index.js.

```
// components/base/_index.js

const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  './',
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  false,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /[A-Z]\w+Base\.vue$/
);

const register = (app) => {
  requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);

    const componentName = fileName
      .split('/')
      .pop()
      ?.replace(/\.\w+$/, '');

    app.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
  });
};

export default {
  register,
};
```

The Button component name must be like this(based on regex): **ButtonBase.vue**

```
// main.js

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import BaseComponents from './components/base/_index';

const app = createApp(App);

BaseComponents.register(app);

app.mount('#app');
```